# representing $E$ as the disjoint union of a finite number of measurable sets that have a measure of at most $\epsilon > 0$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Let, $E$ be a leb. measurable set with a finite leb. measure. Let, $\epsilon > 0 $ and $m$ be the leb. measure. Observe that there exists a set of intervals $\{B_j\}_{j \ge 1}$ such that:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}m(B_j) \le m(E) + \epsilon.$$
Then there exists a $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{j = M}m(B_j)< \epsilon.$$
So,
$$m(\bigcup_{j=N} E \cap B_j )  \le \sum^{\infty}_{j=1} m(B_j) < \epsilon.$$
Let, $S =\bigcup_{j=M} E \cap B_j$. Observe that there exists a $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that:
$$\bigcup_{j=1}^{M-1}B_j \subseteq [a,b].$$
Then we can subdivide $[a,b]$ into a finite collection of intervals of at most length $\epsilon$. Let, those intervals be $\bigcup_{j=1}^{N}B_j'.$ Then,
$$E = S \cup \bigcup^{N}_{j=1}B_j' \cap E.$$
Therefore, the collection $V = \{S,B_1',\dots,B_N'\}$ is the collection we sought.

Does this proof look good? Also why does the question specify disjoint union? Does this imply that each element in $V$ must be disjoint? Thanks.

Comment: Disjoint union means the parts of the union are disjoint. So each two of these finite number of measurable sets must have empty intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That proof looks fine, but it is a bit long. Consider: If $x$ arbitrary then consider $B_\rho(x)\cap E$. Suppose $m(E)>\epsilon$. Then there exists a $\rho$ so that $m(B_\rho(x)\cap E)=\epsilon$. Thus we can write $E$ as disjoint union
$$ E= (B_\rho(x)\cap E)\cup (E\setminus (B_\rho(x)\cap E)) = F_1\cup E_1$$
where one set has measure $\epsilon$ and the other $m(E)-\epsilon$. Thus by iterating this argument $N=[m(E)/\epsilon]$ times we get $m(E_N)<\epsilon$, by which we get such a partition.

Disjoint union means that all sets are pairwise disjoint. This is not really important here, as if we have a union $E=\bigcup F_i$ we can replace $F_i$ by $F_i\setminus \bigcup_{j<i} F_j$ to obtain a disjoint union where each set has at most the measure of the original set (since $F_i\setminus \bigcup_{j<i} F_j\subseteq F_i$).